# How does this return decomposition work?

Tags: equities, returns, historical-data

http://image-src.bcg.com/Images/BCG-Value-Creators-2017-Appendix-July-2017_tcm9-166061.pdf

The paper here decomposes total shareholder return into different components. Here is my derivation of the decomposition, price $P$ and dividend $D$ are in per share basis, other variables ($S$ for shares outstanding) are on firm level:

$$
\begin{eqnarray}
TSR_t &=& \frac{P_t + D_t}{P_{t-1}} \\
 &=& (\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}} + \frac{D_t}{P_{t-1}})\\
 &=& (\frac{P_t/(EBIT_t/S_t)}{P_{t-1}/(EBIT_{t-1}/S_{t-1})}\frac{EBIT_t/S_t}{EBIT_{t-1}/S_{t-1}} + \frac{D_t}{P_{t-1}})\\
 &=& (\frac{P_t/EPS_t}{P_{t-1}/EPS_{t-1}}\frac{EBIT_t}{EBIT_{t-1}} \frac{S_{t-1}}{S_t} + \frac{D_t}{P_{t-1}})\\
 &=& (\frac{P_t/EPS_t}{P_{t-1}/EPS_{t-1}}\frac{Sales_t}{Sales_{t-1}} \frac{S_{t-1}}{S_t}\frac{EBITMargin_t}{EBITMargin_{t-1}} + \frac{D_t}{P_{t-1}})\\
 &\approx& g_{multiple} + g_{sales} + g_{EBITMargin} + g_{shares} + DivYield \\
\end{eqnarray} 
$$
The last step comes from taking log on both sides of the equation.

However, where does that net debt growth part come from?

**Update**

I have done a similar simple decomposition with Amazon, and quickly find that the definition just doesn't work when Earning is negative. One simply cannot take log of a negative number, One can only multiply those terms instead of adding. BCG paper always use sum which doesn' seem like possible. The decomposition that I do as listed above works well when Earning is not negative. As @DavidAddison mentioned, the TRS doesn't match up with my calculation based on my data (Also CaptalIQ).

I think there is still some merits to this decomposition, because you can see what factors drive the return more clearly, at least historically.

Comment: What are $S_t$ and $\mathit{TSR}_t$?

Comment: @MatthewGunn $S_t$ represents the number of shares outstanding and $TSR_t$ is the total shareholder return.

Comment: So why is $\frac{S_t}{S_{t-1}}$ there? Issuing new shares at the current price doesn't generate positive returns. Retiring shares at the current price doesn't generate negative returns.

Comment: @MatthewGunn at time t-1, we pay total P(t-1)S(t-1) for the whole equity, if the firm issues new shares between t-1 and t at t price of P(t-1), then S(t) is greater than S(t-1), and P(t) and D(t) should be adjusted automatically downwards since people who buys new shares know that each share value is diluted. The numerator just represents Total Firm Equity Value at time t and denomintor represents the total firm equity value at time t-1.

Comment: Imagine I have a firm with assets of \$10 in cash, and the firm also has 10 shares. $S_t = 1$. Each share is worth \$1. $P_t = 1$. The firm value $S_tP_t = 10$. The firm then issues 90 additional shares for \$1 each. So it then has \$100 in cash and is worth \$100. $P_{t+1}S_{t+1} = 100$. The firm has 100 shares. $S_{t+1} = 100$. Therefore the price $P_{t+1} = 1$. The total shareholder return is zero.

Comment: @MatthewGunn oop, you made a good point. Then there will be an additional question to my original question, where does that share issuance term come from in the BCG paper?

Comment: Can you find any references where they precisely define terms?

Comment: @MatthewGunn I would hope they have the reference for how they decompose tit as well...

Comment: First off, has anyone checked that BCG’s TSR matches up with actual market returns for common equity? If so, then this is a true decomposition. If not, it is just a metric and too much effort spent reconciling the two might be pointless.

Comment: @DavidAddison I have tried to perform the TSR for the company Ryohin Keikaku, and I get arithmetic average TSR for 2012-2016 as 52% instead of their 46%. When I decompose it using my way as illustrated above, the components are of similar magnitude. I think they have followed similar procedure, but using different periods